# Any tutorial to How to self-host your own ETH

Tags: go-ethereum

Yesterday I ask a Q to know if I can create my own self-host ETH and people come and create their tokens and I get answer YES!

And now I want to know how to do this?

Which repo I should clone?
Which commands I should use?
and...

Comment: Search for any tutorial how to launch a private test network.